# Terminology of atomic spectroscopy: Difference Among Term, States and Level

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, terminology, atomic-structure

In [A Primer on 
Quantum Numbers and Spectroscopic Notation
Contents](http://www.astro.sunysb.edu/fwalter/AST341/qn.html), the concept of a term and level is described as

> a) The level is the set of 2J+1 states with specific values of L, S,
>   and J. The difference in the energy between two levels gives the
>   wavelength or frequency of an atomic transition.
>
> b) The term is the set of levels characterized by a specific S and L.

1) Is there a better way to understand the subtle difference among the concept of a level, a state, and a term. A example would be helpful.

2) A side question is what are the German equivalents of term, state and level. What do they call it in atomic spectroscopy literature? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The figure below shows the situation between configuration for a $p^2$ configuration, terms, levels and states. The word 'state' tends to be used colloquially to mean any of  Term, Level or State.

The *Configuration* such as  $(1s)^2$ or ...$(2p)^2$ etc. tell us which orbitals are occupied.

These are split with electrostatic (Coulomb) coupling to form *Terms*.

The Term Symbol informs about the angular momentum. The number of levels in each *Term* is $(2J+1)$, the number of *States* is $(2L+1)(2S+1)$ .

The term symbol is

$$\large ^{2S+1}L_J$$

where $S$ is the total spin and $L$ the orbital angular momentum.  $J$ represents the angular momentum as quantum numbers $(J=L+S)$ and is determined by adding individual spin numbers according to Glebsch-Gordon series, i.e. if $q_1,\,q_2$ are angular momentum quantum numbers  then the series is all terms (separated by unit steps) with values $q_1+q_2 , q_1+q_2-1,\cdots \to |q_1-q_2|$. (There may be only be term).

The *Terms* are split with a magnetic interaction such as spin-orbit coupling, i.e coupling of spin angular momentum with that of the orbital. It is not present for S orbitals because here $L=0$.

*Levels* are distinguished by total angular momentum $J$, and are $2J+1$ degenerate.

An external magnetic field will remove all remaining degeneracy to form *States*. These are distinguished by $m_J$ and there are $2J+1$ of them.

[image: term level states]

Comment: Excellent. Could you share the reference for this figure? So in a rigorous sense, when we talk about electronic transitions in atomic spectra, the transitions are in levels. And transition among states can be seen in Zeeman effect.

Comment: I used the figure in lectures years ago, and I don't recall where it came from  so perhaps drew it. And yes Zeeman effect (or Stark) splits levels to make states so this spectroscopy identifies states. I think this was how these energy levels were discovered in the first place; anomalous Zeeman effect and all that history.

Comment: The concept of terms is really old, and the origin is most likely from the series concept, where each member of series is called a term.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the side question about German language terminology, I'll pick up terms from @porphyrin's answer.

But first of all, term = `Term` (same as in maths)

> The word 'state' tends to be used colloquially to mean any of Term, Level or State.

All those colloquial states are `Zustände` (pl., sg. `Zustand`) in German or you can use `Term`, `Niveau` (level) and `Zustand` (state). 
I'd say that in German, `Zustand` is an `Oberbegriff` (umbrella term) that includes specific types of `Zustände` such as `Terme` (`Zustand` with fixed L and S) and `Niveaus` (`Zustand` with fixed L, S, and J).

angular momentum = `Drehimpuls` (drehen = to turn, Impuls = momentum)
But `Eigendrehimpuls` ("intrinsic angular momentum") is usually just `Spin` also in German.
Thus, the `Anzahl der Zustände` (2S + 1) is the `Spinmultiplizität`.

spin-orbit-coupling = `Spin-Bahn-Kopplung` or `Spin-Bahn-Wechselwirkung`

degenerate = `entartet`

See e.g. The German wiki page https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-Bahn-Kopplung#LS-Kopplung_bei_mehreren_Elektronen for all those terms in their native environment.

---